# Elixir/Phoenix pass payload on joining channel

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

Channels have the `authorized?` function, and I would like to pass the generated local token when joining the channel so that I can verify user's role, like this:

```
const data = { token: localStorage.getItem('phoenixAuthToken') };
channel.join(data).receive('ok', (response) => {
            ...
            });
        });
```

However, in my channel setup, I don't seem to receive anything from client on join:

```
def join("settings", payload, socket) do
  IO.inspect(payload)
  if authorized?(payload) do
    {:ok, socket}
  else
    {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
  end
end
```

`IO.inspect(payload)` is just `%{}`. What I'm doing wrong here? Is it even possible to receive the message when joining the channel?

Comment: Try attaching the data when you call `.channel()`, e.g. `channel = socket.channel("foo", { token: ... })` and then just do `channel.join()`.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks man!! I was just passing it then the wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The payload that `join/3` receives is the [one set in the second argument of `.channel()`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/506ffb37a66813cc988a3618a0d48cec7a410e04/assets/js/phoenix.js#L26) in the JS client side, not the argument passed to `.join()`. So, on the client side, you should be doing something like:

```
const data = { token: localStorage.getItem('phoenixAuthToken') };
const channel = socket.channel("foo", data);
channel.join().receive(...);
```